# Check date and take another item from django queryset

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

I have django app (with django app 1.8 and django rest framework 3.3.1). I have model wiht Event and I want to display only last 4 events but if is 10 min after date_start I want to get another last 4 event.

I'm not sure if my code it works correctly.

```
class BoxView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Events.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BoxSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        last_events_list = Events.objects.all().order_by('-date_start')[:4]
        for i in last_events_list:
            if i.date_start < now() + timedelta(minutes=10):
                return last_events_list
            else:
                return last_events_list
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to filter the events with [`__lt`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#lt)

```
before = now() + timedelta(minutes=10)
last_events_list = Events.objects.filter(date_start__lt=before).order_by('-date_start')[:4]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That was brilliant!